# How can I customize the dialog box message when user leaving or refreshing the for page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I used `beforeUnload` event listener, but I couldn't get the message I want to be displayed on dialog-box.
Here is my code:

```
//code//[enter image description here][1]
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  
  var message = ' customized message ';
  (window.event).returnValue = message;
  return message;
});
```

Note; can I use `preventDefault()` method instead return value?
I tried with

```
{event.preventDefault();
   return message;}
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not wrong, the problem is that not all browsers display the returned message. Prevent default won't help you.

Quoting [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload):

> Some browsers display the returned string in the dialog box, but others display their own message. If no value is provided, the event is processed silently.

For better cross-browser results, keep appending the message to the event handler and don't just return the message.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  var message = ' customized message ';

  event.returnValue = message; // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return message;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```